# Is G++ 5.1's `-Wctor-dtor-privacy` warning broken?

Tags: gcc, g++, clang++, gcc-warning, g++5.1

The `ctor-dtor-privacy` warning is intended to be triggered when [all constructors and destructors are private](https://books.google.com/books?id=wQ6r3UTivJgC&lpg=PA45&ots=ELWnVnbCDz&dq=gcc%20ctor-dtor-privacy&pg=PA46#v=onepage&q=%22warning%20when%20all%20constructors%20and%20destructors%22&f=false).

So for the following class, I would expect warning to trigger:

```
struct foo
{
  public:
    static int test(void) { return 3; };
  private:
    foo(void) {}
};
```

But neither `clang++` (version `clang 3.7.0 (trunk 238948)`) nor GCC 5.1.0 issues a warning for this code when using `-Wctor-dtor-privacy`. This seems suspicious, but warnings aren't perfect, so some false negatives are to be expected, I suppose. (Perhaps the warning doesn't get triggered because the copy and move constructors are still implicitly defined, so technically not *all* constructors are private--even though the class still can't be constructed.)

However, this code does get a warning:

```
struct foo
{
  private:
    static int test(void) { return 3; };
  // private:
  //   foo(void) {}
};
```

Here, `test` is made `private` and the explicit constructor is removed so that `foo`'s constructor is implicitly defined. G++ gives the following warning:

```
 warning: all member functions in class ‘foo’ are private [-Wctor-dtor-privacy]
```

`clang++` gives no warning.

This warning *certainly* seems incorrect, since there is an implicit public constructor. What's going on here? Is this a bug?

**EDIT:** It seems that perhaps Clang++ doesn't *ever* issue a warning. Even the following class does not trigger any warnings with `-Wctor-dtor-privacy`:

```
class ReallyTrulyPrivateOnly
{
  private:
    ReallyTrulyPrivateOnly(void) =default;
    ReallyTrulyPrivateOnly(ReallyTrulyPrivateOnly&&) =default;
    ReallyTrulyPrivateOnly(const ReallyTrulyPrivateOnly&) =default;
  public:
    void foo(void) {}
};
```

So perhaps this warning is simply provided for G++ command-line compatibility, but actually does nothing? (Note that this class generates a quite sensible warning with GCC: `warning: ‘class ReallyTrulyPrivateOnly’ only defines private constructors and has no friends [-Wctor-dtor-privacy]`)

**EDIT 2:** I believe the behavior of this warning is not well understood or documented, and that this issue was noticed and reported in [bug 55813](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55813). This was marked "fixed" in release 4.8, but since the behavior still seems suspect to me, I've added a comment pointing back to this question.

**EDIT 3:** The bug in the above edit is *not* the same issue; I have opened a [new bug report (71484)](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=71484) for this issue.

Comment: `-Wctor-dtor-privacy` is apparently a misnomer. g++ warns when all (explicitly declared) member functions are private, not just ctors and dtors.

Comment: @n.m. Actually, I mistyped the `ReallyTrulyPrivateOnly` example: the `only defines private constructors` g++ warning is only issued when `foo` is `public`. When `foo` is `private`, I get the original `all member functions...are private` message.

Comment: .....so....I guess this is really *two* warnings: one indicating that you can't actually *construct* the class, and one indicating that the class has uncallable members.

Comment: clang indeed only accepts this warning flag for gcc compatibility, and does not warn. https://clang.llvm.org/docs/DiagnosticsReference.html#wctor-dtor-privacy